# How can I create a click handler than can only be clicked once?

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function incr() { 
var v1=document.getElementById('p1').value;
document.getElementById("p1").value= v1 + 1;
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<form id="form_Warpper" action="data.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
    <progress value="0" max="100" id="p1"></progress>
                <p> 1. </p>
                <label> I am sexy. </label>
                <div class="allQuestion"><?php for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){?><input type="radio" name="Dq[1]" value="<?=$i?>" onClick='incr();'> <?=$i?> <?php } ?></div>
                </div>
</body>
```

I need to put onclick but only want it to be able to be clicked once. I have 100 questions. I only need it to increase the percentage when the radio is clicked. It should only be able to be clicked once but this one, if I clicked it again it keep increasing.  How can I get it to only be clicked once?

cause i have 10 question i cant use true or false to turn on and off.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to user jquery one() function. For example,

```
$( "#foo" ).one( "click", function() {
  alert( "This will be displayed only once." );
});
```

Here is the like for one() http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: i dont wanted to use jquery any idea how ? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var trigger = 0;

function incr() { 

    if (trigger == 0) { 

        var v1=document.getElementById('p1').value;

        document.getElementById("p1").value= v1 + 1;

        trigger = 1;

    };

};
```

Answer (score 0):

There is couple of way you can do it , one of them is to disable the radio button group once user have selected the value , otherwise keep a global variable like this

```
                   <script>
                   var updated = false;
                    function incr() { 
                        if(updated == false){
                         var v1=document.getElementById('p1').value;
                         document.getElementById("p1").value= v1 + 1;
                         updated = true;
                         }
                      }
                   </script>
```

Comment: but i also using this for other question , i got like 10 question using the same incr to off the group , but if just turn off by 1 question other wont function as well. thank for helping

Comment: I agree that is why i have given the code where you do not need to disable but set the flag

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use jQuery, you can create your own once function very easily.

```
function once(fn) {
    var called = false;
    return function () {
        !called && fn();
        called = true;
    }
}
```

Here's an example of how to use it http://codepen.io/zachwolf/pen/jEyZqY

Comment: but i also have other question , if it become false my other question wont be able to clicked it again.

Comment: No, the variable is local to the execution of the function.